# How do I generate a variable sized list from a given list using Hypothesis?

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

For property-based testing, given a fixed list of values, I need to generate a variable-sized list where order is important and duplicates are allowed. For example, if my fixed list is

```
texts = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4']
```

I would like to generate different variations, e.g.

```
['t2']
['t4', 't1'] # Subset and different order
[]
['t3', 't1', 't2'] # Different order
['t4', 't4', 't4', 't1'] # Repetition of t4
['t1', 't2', 't1'] # Repetition but at different location
['t1', 't2']
['t2', 't1'] # different order from the one above and considered different.
```

What I have managed to use currently is the `permutations` strategy

```
from hypothesis import given, strategies as st

@given(st.permutations(texts))
def test_x(some_text):
   ...
   pass
```

But that does not give me variable size, repetitions

Other requirements:

- How can I specify a maximum variable list of 20?

Comment: `lists(sampled_from(texts), max_size=20)`? I'm just not sure what you mean by the "order is important" requirement. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Georgy Thanks! I meant that the strategy should serve `['t1', 't2']` as well as `["t2", "t1"]` i.e permutations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a combination of the [`lists`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.lists) and the [`sampled_from`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.sampled_from) strategies:

```
from hypothesis import strategies as st

texts = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4']
lists_from_texts = st.lists(st.sampled_from(texts), max_size=20)

...

@given(lists_from_texts)
def test_x(some_text):
    ...
```

or if you want to be able to change the source list for different tests:

```
from typing import List


def lists_from_texts(source: List[str]) -> st.SearchStrategy[List[str]]:
    return st.lists(st.sampled_from(source), max_size=20)

...

@given(lists_from_texts(texts))
def test_x(some_text):
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you want at most 20 items, generate a random number from 1 to 20:

```
import random
size = random.randint(1,20)
```

Then use that number to make N number of independent choices from your source list:

```
texts = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4']
random_texts = []
for _ in range(size):
    random_texts.append(random.choice(texts))
```

Comment: I wish I could select this answer too. Though I was using this question as a means to learn python-hypothesis, you showed me  something I could use in other places as well. Thanks. upvoted.